# How to dynamically get value of button using VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have created a dynamic list of buttons, which have genres of music.

When users click on a button genre, example: Pop, I need to perform a search for media that matches that genre. Users can select more than 1 button. So, maybe they want to see Pop, Rock, and Rap music genres.

My problem is, I can't seem to find a way to get the genre of the button (Pop, Rock, Rap, etc.) from my `index.html` and send it to my VueJS to re-perform the search.

This is my `script.js`, and the method I am trying to implement right now. Unfortunately, it only ever prints out `undefined`:

```
// Get Selected Genres
getGenre(value) {
  alert('Hello ' + this.value); // trying to print out Pop, Rock, Rap, etc.
}
```

I've tried the following in `index.html`, where I am trying to pass in the value to the getGenre function, but it just makes the web page fail to load. I've also tried this *without* the {{ }}, but it just prints `undefined`.

```
<li v-for="buttons in buttonsList" style="display: inline;">
    <button v-if="ShowALLButton" v-on:click="getGenre({{buttons}})" class = "btn" style="border: 2px solid darkgrey; margin:2px;">{{ buttons }}</button>
</li>
```

I've also tried this in `script.js`:

```
// Get Selected Genres
getGenre: function(event) {
  alert('Hello ' + this.value);
}
```

As well as this in my `index.html`, where I try to set the value to `buttons` (both WITH and without {{ }}), but it prints `undefined`.

```
<li v-for="buttons in buttonsList" style="display: inline;">
    <button v-if="ShowALLButton" v-on:click="getGenre()" value="buttons" class = "btn" style="border: 2px solid darkgrey; margin:2px;">{{ buttons }}</button>
</li>
```

Basically, I need to know what the button value is so I can re-do my search and show only media in the selected genres, but I am struggling with VueJS syntax. How can I do this?

Comment: `v-on:click="getGenre({{buttons}})"` <= remove the `{{}}` around buttons.

Comment: `v-on:click="getGenre(buttons)"` should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use template interpolation within the `v-for` as the `buttons` is an expression of type `string | null | number | object | array | undefined`, so you can just pass that as an argument:

```
v-on:click="getGenre(buttons)"
```